# What is the difference between length of a list and number of a list in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Is there any difference between the 2?

I've been using number of list for quite a long time now, but I noticed that length was also reserved for Applescript, and that it seemed to have the same function as number....

But its highlighted purple instead of blue.

Are they exactly the same, or are they different? And which one would you suggest using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although both expressions have the same result, there is a difference.

- `number of` — which is a synonym for `count` — evaluates the number of items when it's called.
- `length` is a property of the class `list` which implies that the class maintains the value constantly and there is no further evaluation when it's called.

I'd prefer the latter.